# Как сделать объединение ячеек инвентаря в unity

Tags: массивы, unity3d, разработка-игр, ui

Допустим есть некий инвентарь и элемент занимающий две ячейки то как сделать чтоб он занимал именнно две ? Был варинт что каждая ячейка должна иметь ссылки на ячейки что находятся рядом от нее и сделать функцию проверки соседней ячейки на пустоту. и если все ячейки в нужном диапазоне пусты то мы заполняем ячейку от куда пошла проверка нужным элементом, а ячейки что в диапозоне мы заполняем ссылкой на элемент корневой ячейки, что б они небыли пусты. Логика самого инвентаря понятна но как реализовать это графически в юнити ? растягивать ячейку на нужные позиции а соседнии прикрывать ?

Comment: Это зависит. У вас уже есть реализация инвентаря? Хоть набросок?

Comment: @eastwing, прка нету, есть толькоою граф часть, и вот сейчас логику продумываю

Comment: Ну, в целом - примерно так: каждый предмет занимает сколько-то клеток (MxN). Когда вы бросаете предмет в инвентарь, надо определить, на какой клетке **предмета** был курсор (или палец), на какую клетку **инвентаря** упала клетка, на которой был курсор, и от этой клетки инвентаря проверить нужное количество оставшихся клеток в нужные стороны. Графически клетки инвентаря друг на друга накладывать не надо

Comment: Логика более менее понятна, но как сделать тогда графическую часть ?

Comment: Ну, наверное, как обычно - при помощи Unity UI